# iPad showing White Screen instead of Home Page on Navigation

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am working on Xamarin Forms project. Project uses Prism library. With latest iOS update i am having issues. Here is what should happen

On logging in, a screen pops up asking users to choose group. On selecting group, App should navigate to Accounts page (Detail page which is tabbed page of Master Detail page) and display accounts list. Everything is working as excepted until ios 13 and Xcode 11 update. Once i updated Xcode and Visual Studio, i am having issues in displaying Accounts page. Everything is working good across iPhone and Android but on iPad instead of displaying Accounts page, App is displaying White page in Content section along with tabs at the bottom of the page.

The only change i made in my code is wrote the below code in Navigation Render because App is displaying Groups page as a card instead of full Scree.

```
public override void WillMoveToParentViewController(UIViewController parent)
{
    base.WillMoveToParentViewController(parent);
    parent.ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.FullScreen;
}
```

Tried commenting this piece of code but still white screen is displaying instead of Accounts page.

**Note: The error is only on iPad running iOS 13.**

Please help me in fixing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try to update Xamarin.Forms. I had the same issue and I solved upgrading to latest Xamarin Forms 3.6.x version as described here

[described here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/7654)

Comment: This helped me, and I was very lost and had no idea where to start, thank you very much!